# Porting C# mono to dotnet core

Tags: c#, mono, .net-core

I have a simple C# mono project and I want to port it to dotnet core. It uses `FluentNHibernate`.

I have created a new project using `dotnet new` and copied the sources to my new project. I modified the `project.json` file to use `net452` and included the `FluentNHibernate` dependency. Here is my file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"dependencies": { },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "FluentNHibernate": "2.0.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running `dotnet restores` runs without errors, but when I run `dotnet run` I get namespace errors:

```
/ILRBdotnet/obj/Debug/net452/dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(2,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

All errors point out that `System` (or any other `System.String`) type or namespace could not be found. What am I missing?

Comment: try to remove `bin` and `obj` folders and again use `dotnet build`. It should create correct `dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs` file.

Comment: @Set i tried that, but no effect.